# Receive data sent from C++ server on C# client

Tags: c#, c++

The C++ server will send a struct like this to C# client:

```
typedef struct {

    int cmd;             //commend of order
    int state;           //the state of communication
    int step;            //the step
    int dataLength;      //data length
    char data[DATA_SIZE];//data
} Message;
```

I want to use a C# client to *receive* the struct and access members and data, how can I do that?

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz How does that help? Its a custom message, not something defined in a windows DLL, and the OP doesn't mention anything about p/invoke. It would be relatively simple to copy the struct style in C#, the problem comes in with knowing how much data to read, which again isn't hard if its one message per packet, but it isn't specified about how its sent.

Comment: @RonBeyer, there are many examples there of how to pass structs/classes between c# and C++/C. It's an educational site. Yes, it's mostly Windows APIs, but so what? Presumably the OP is calling some C/C++ method from C#. Hence there are lots of examples of doing that at pinvoke.net

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz But he isn't passing it between C++ and C#, its coming over a socket or other IPC method and its source is irrelevant, C++ is only identified because it outlines the format. There isn't anything here to say that the client and server share any DLL's or any type of p/invoke mechanism.

Comment: @RonBeyer, he didn't specifically mention how he's getting the information. And he **IS** passing it between C++ and C# and I quote: "The C++ server will send a struct like this to C# client:". It matters not if he's getting the bytes over a socket or through a function call. The marshalling is the same. I know. I've done both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this problem ,I define the struct in c# like this :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Pack =1), Serializable]
    struct Message
    {
        public int cmd;
        public int state;
        public int step;
        public int dataLength;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
        public string ip_segment;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1024)]
        public byte[] data;
    }
```

when I received a byte array I convert it to the Message like this :

```
public object BytesToStruct(byte[] bytes, Type type)
        {
            //get the size of Message
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(type);

            if (size > bytes.Length)
            {

                return null;
            }
            //allocate Message object space
            IntPtr structPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            //copy the byte array to the space
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, structPtr, size);
            //convert byte array to struct Message
            object obj = Marshal.PtrToStructure(structPtr, type);
            //free the space
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(structPtr);
            //return object
            return obj;
        }
```